# NSolve Duration for simultaneous equations solving

Tags: equation-solving

At the moment I am asking myself why mathematica gets to point of needing enormous amount of time to solve equations like these when one more "row" or "colum" or both was added in this equations construct (so this example was solved quite fast by contrast):

$$ \tiny \left(\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1-0.0496594 c_{0,1} \\
 0.0019892 \left(1-0.0496594 c_{1,1}\right) \\
 0.529849 \left(1-0.0496594 c_{2,1}\right) \\
 0.0557129 \left(1-0.0496594 c_{3,1}\right) \\
 0.412449 \left(1-0.0496594 c_{4,1}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c_{-1,1} \\
 \text{pr}_1 c_{-1,1} \\
 \text{pr}_2 c_{-1,1} \\
 \text{pr}_3 c_{-1,1} \\
 \text{pr}_4 c_{-1,1} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left\{c_{0,1}+\text{pr}_1 \left(c_{1,1}-294\right)+\text{pr}_2 \left(c_{2,1}-95\right)+\text{pr}_3 \left(c_{3,1}-299\right)+\text{pr}_4 \left(c_{4,1}-261\right)-218\right\}=0,\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1-0.0404094 c_{0,2} \\
 0.155462 \left(1-0.0404094 c_{1,2}\right) \\
 0.355855 \left(1-0.0404094 c_{2,2}\right) \\
 0.0932882 \left(1-0.0404094 c_{3,2}\right) \\
 0.395395 \left(1-0.0404094 c_{4,2}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c_{-1,2} \\
 \text{pr}_1 c_{-1,2} \\
 \text{pr}_2 c_{-1,2} \\
 \text{pr}_3 c_{-1,2} \\
 \text{pr}_4 c_{-1,2} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left\{c_{0,2}+\text{pr}_1 \left(c_{1,2}-69\right)+\text{pr}_2 \left(c_{2,2}-66\right)+\text{pr}_3 \left(c_{3,2}-79\right)+\text{pr}_4 \left(c_{4,2}-230\right)-292\right\}=0,\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1-0.0635522 c_{0,3} \\
 0.227094 \left(1-0.0635522 c_{1,3}\right) \\
 0.107208 \left(1-0.0635522 c_{2,3}\right) \\
 0.298219 \left(1-0.0635522 c_{3,3}\right) \\
 0.367479 \left(1-0.0635522 c_{4,3}\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 c_{-1,3} \\
 \text{pr}_1 c_{-1,3} \\
 \text{pr}_2 c_{-1,3} \\
 \text{pr}_3 c_{-1,3} \\
 \text{pr}_4 c_{-1,3} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left\{c_{0,3}+\text{pr}_1 \left(c_{1,3}-277\right)+\text{pr}_2 \left(c_{2,3}-209\right)+\text{pr}_3 \left(c_{3,3}-167\right)+\text{pr}_4 \left(c_{4,3}-242\right)-64\right\}=0,c_{0,1}+c_{0,2}+c_{0,3}-574=0,c_{1,1}+c_{1,2}+c_{1,3}-640=0,c_{2,1}+c_{2,2}+c_{2,3}-370=0,c_{3,1}+c_{3,2}+c_{3,3}-545=0,c_{0,1}-218=-\left(4 \text{pr}_1+9 \text{pr}_2+4 \text{pr}_3+9 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{1,1}-\left(2 \text{pr}_1+5 \text{pr}_2+6 \text{pr}_3+5 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{2,1}-\left(8 \text{pr}_1+2 \text{pr}_2+6 \text{pr}_3+6 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{3,1}-\left(\text{pr}_1+4 \text{pr}_2+4 \text{pr}_3+7 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{4,1},c_{1,1}-294=4 \theta _{1,1}+2 \theta _{2,1}+8 \theta _{3,1}+\theta _{4,1},c_{2,1}-95=9 \theta _{1,1}+5 \theta _{2,1}+2 \theta _{3,1}+4 \theta _{4,1},c_{3,1}-299=4 \theta _{1,1}+6 \theta _{2,1}+6 \theta _{3,1}+4 \theta _{4,1},c_{4,1}-261=9 \theta _{1,1}+5 \theta _{2,1}+6 \theta _{3,1}+7 \theta _{4,1},c_{0,2}-292=-\left(4 \text{pr}_1+9 \text{pr}_2+4 \text{pr}_3+9 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{1,2}-\left(2 \text{pr}_1+5 \text{pr}_2+6 \text{pr}_3+5 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{2,2}-\left(8 \text{pr}_1+2 \text{pr}_2+6 \text{pr}_3+6 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{3,2}-\left(\text{pr}_1+4 \text{pr}_2+4 \text{pr}_3+7 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{4,2},c_{1,2}-69=4 \theta _{1,2}+2 \theta _{2,2}+8 \theta _{3,2}+\theta _{4,2},c_{2,2}-66=9 \theta _{1,2}+5 \theta _{2,2}+2 \theta _{3,2}+4 \theta _{4,2},c_{3,2}-79=4 \theta _{1,2}+6 \theta _{2,2}+6 \theta _{3,2}+4 \theta _{4,2},c_{4,2}-230=9 \theta _{1,2}+5 \theta _{2,2}+6 \theta _{3,2}+7 \theta _{4,2},c_{0,3}-64=-\left(4 \text{pr}_1+9 \text{pr}_2+4 \text{pr}_3+9 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{1,3}-\left(2 \text{pr}_1+5 \text{pr}_2+6 \text{pr}_3+5 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{2,3}-\left(8 \text{pr}_1+2 \text{pr}_2+6 \text{pr}_3+6 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{3,3}-\left(\text{pr}_1+4 \text{pr}_2+4 \text{pr}_3+7 \text{pr}_4\right) \theta _{4,3},c_{1,3}-277=4 \theta _{1,3}+2 \theta _{2,3}+8 \theta _{3,3}+\theta _{4,3},c_{2,3}-209=9 \theta _{1,3}+5 \theta _{2,3}+2 \theta _{3,3}+4 \theta _{4,3},c_{3,3}-167=4 \theta _{1,3}+6 \theta _{2,3}+6 \theta _{3,3}+4 \theta _{4,3},c_{4,3}-242=9 \theta _{1,3}+5 \theta _{2,3}+6 \theta _{3,3}+7 \theta _{4,3},\left\{\theta _{1,1}+\theta _{1,2}+\theta _{1,3},\theta _{2,1}+\theta _{2,2}+\theta _{2,3},\theta _{3,1}+\theta _{3,2}+\theta _{3,3},\theta _{4,1}+\theta _{4,2}+\theta _{4,3}\right\}=\{0,0,0,0\}\right\}\right.$$

Here's a link to the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/luwpwgpl91rd6gv/fineco_lagrange_single-multi_web.nb?dl=0).
To change the number of equations, simply modify

```
    n = 5
    m = 3
```

The purpose is a demonstration like this one:

[image]

The *single dots* represent "***aggregate endowments***", the *blue line* "***individual endowments***" for all possible states and the *orange line* features the "***utility maximized consumption***" depending on individuals propability estimations on the states being realized. 
The **right graphics** shows the *demand for securities* (number of securities = number of states). It can be seen which security demand choice leads to a difference in consumption vs endowment in some states.

For m=2 it is possible to get a solution for n=45 in about 10-20 min.
The graphics look like this:

[image]

For any solutions for speeding up I am very grateful.

Comment: (1) I was not able to get the code to parse. (2) It appears that the equations are not linear. Which means the complexity of the solving process can be considerable. (3) You might want to try `FindRoot`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Do you mean the code won't yield solutions in your case? Do you also use Wolfram M. version 10? For FindRoot, how to I convert a list of equations into "&&" sets? FindRoot always complains about the number of equations.

Comment: It should yield a consumption vector in similar fashion (random numbers are generated on each run)

$ \small \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \{284.231,260.105,142.008,52.2613,149.109\} & \{285.769,154.895,328.992,257.739,51.8908\} \\
\end{array}
\right)$